# Is it possible to enforce permissions within a trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, permissions

Given that Apex Triggers run within a system context, if I then include any kind of permission check, like isUpdateable() will that actually reflect the users permissions that invoked the trigger?

```
If(Case.Subject.getDescribe().isUpdateable() == False)
{
// then do this...
}
```

In the above code, if within a trigger, would //then do this... ever be reachable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding this code, you are introducing permission checks yourself. So yes, depending on the permissions set for the user that the code is running under, you will be executing whatever logical branches you add.

Such guards in triggers added to *standard* objects are a very good idea. You can't assume that every user in the org has the access rights that your specific users have. And if they don't, your trigger will be responsible for blocking their work on the standard object (by blowing up with a permission error), making you a very unpopular person.

(Yes someone with object level rights on `Case` is going to have field access rights on `Subject`, but with more obscure fields, maybe not.)

Comment: Thanks @Keith C, this is exactly as I thought, but the documentation was unclear, so was second guessing myself!